# Websocket, recuperar información

Tags: python, websocket

Estoy desarrollando un "bot" encargado de consumir información de un nodo Ethereum, la conexión establecida es a través de websockets, ya que se trata de información en tiempo real.

Aquí viene mi duda, como NO perder información frente a eventualidades? Una desconexión y reconexión me toma unos minutos y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de recuperar los datos correspondientes a ese periodo de tiempo. Estoy comenzando con las lecturas al respecto y agradezco cualquier orientación. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes guardar en el disco los datos cada cierto tiempo. Además de hacerlo cuando la conexión es cerrada normalmente (es decir, no fue forzada por ejemplo por un corte de luz). Obviamente, no se puede evitar del todo perder información frente a eventualidades, pero al menos se pierde mucho menos.

Comment: Comprendo el punto, y agradezco la pronta respuesta. Investigaré por ese lado entonces, estaba leyendo un poco acerca de subprotcol, comprendiendo como funciona websocket a un nivel mas inferior, pero la verdad que no tenía del todo claro como encararlo. Saludos.